# Query composite index query in Dynamo

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a DynamoDB table with following keys:

```
id: partition key
created_at: sort key
brand#category#size#color: partition key for global index 'byAttributes'
```

The global index partition key is a composite of 4 table attributes using '#' as a delimiter.

Is there a way in DynamoDB that I can query the table using only a subset of the attributes using a wildcard for unspecified attributes?

As examples:

```
byAttributes = 'levis#shirts#*#red'
byAttributes = '*#pants#L#*'
```

I don't wish to use a FilterExpression because it only filters data after a search. I want to take advantage of the attributes being indexed.

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can create alternative GSIs for different combinations.

You can also include a hierarchical SK value and use begins-with to limit based on zero or more values.

Putting some values in the PK and the rest in a hierarchical SK achieves a lot of combinations.

For example have a GSI:

PK = category,
SK = size#brand#color

Now you can query by category, category/size, category/size/brand, or all four.

If it gets more than four you may want to look at Rockset as an indexing system against DynamoDB data.